# How to print multiple rows data in one page in crystal report? (Data is stored in a datatable) 

Tags: c#

I have created a data table with multiple data records. I want to print data of specific columns for each row to crystal report. For instance, the print-out should show 6 rows of data in 1st page and next 6 rows of data in 2nd page with specific format.

What I've done is printing each row of data in one page, which is wasting my papers.

Looking forward to any kind answers :)

Answer (score 0):

Add your columns to **Details** section of Crystal Report.
 Then right click on **Details** section, select **Section Expert** from pop-up menu. Select **Paging** tab. Check the box **New Page After -> * visible records** and change number from 1 to 6.

Hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks for your kind info. But, I've tried in your way and it doesn't work as well. My 6 pages are gone again :( Any more suggestions? Thanks in advance